# Send and listen to multiple queues of rabbitMQ using java

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have 2 types of queues for each message type - 
1. REQUEST_QUEUE - for sending message 2. RESPONSE_QUEUE - for getting message response.

So if there are 5 message type, we have 10 queues.

As a client, I want to send message to all request queue and need to listen to response queue as per correlation id. 
for publish a message I am using below code:

```
public static void publishMessage(String exchange, String routingKey, String responseKey, List<String> messageList) throws IOException, Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(Constants.rabbitMQServerProperties.HOST_NAME);
    factory.setUsername(Constants.rabbitMQServerProperties.USER_NAME);
    factory.setPassword(Constants.rabbitMQServerProperties.PASSWORD);
    factory.setPort(Constants.rabbitMQServerProperties.PORT);
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    //System.out.println(channel.isOpen());
    //System.out.println(message);
    for(String message : messageList) {
        channel.basicPublish(exchange, routingKey, true, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC,  message.getBytes());
    }
    channel.close();
    connection.close();
    System.out.println("Message published successfully!\n \n");
    Connection con = factory.newConnection();
    // ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    // listen to response queue
    Worker fast = new Worker(0, threadExecutor, con.createChannel(), responseKey);
}
```

on last line, once I sent messages, I am listening to message queue.

Worker.java:

```
public class Worker extends DefaultConsumer {
    String name;
    Channel channel;
    String queue;
    int processed;
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public Worker(int prefetch, ExecutorService threadExecutor, Channel c, String q) throws Exception {
        super(c);
        channel = c;
        queue = q;
        channel.basicQos(prefetch);
        channel.basicConsume(queue, false, this);
        executorService = threadExecutor;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                               Envelope envelope,
                               AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                               byte[] body) throws IOException {
        String response = new String(body);
        String routingKey = envelope.getRoutingKey();
        String contentType = properties.getContentType();
        String correlationId = properties.getCorrelationId();
        System.out.println(queue+" Response :: "+ response);

        }

    }
}
```

Below are my problems:

1. While listening to queue I need to pick only my messages which I have submitted (lets say, I have list of correlation ids with me) and if it is not from my corrleation id, then I need to send message back to response queue. How can I do here?
2. once I got all message I need to close the my open connection.
3. If I am sending messages to all 5 the queues one by one, is my approach of sending & listening is proper?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds less like queue and more like topic to me.  I don't like the idea of duplicating a message on five queues - violates DRY.

Comment: There are 5 different queues with different purposes, and they have response queue to response. I need to send messages to each queue as client and need to read response.

Comment: Could make it request and response topics, with five separate topics.  Let clients register themselves as listeners on response topic for the ones they're interested in.

Comment: thanks @duffymo, my scenario is already implemented, I just need to test it by sending a messages and getting the response. I respect your suggestion but I can't change the implementation!